# Adjust Flyout position when it has been automatically repositioned

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

See a demo here

[image: See a demo here.]

I have a UWP app that has a `ListView` with selectable list items as shown. Selecting the right side of the item opens a `Flyout` (not a `MenuFlyout`). I specify the `Placement` of the `Flyout` to be `Bottom`, and a `Margin` of `0, -4, 0, 0` in the `FlyoutPresenter` Style. This results in the desired appearance, with the `Flyout` directly below and adjacent to the item.

However, if there isn't enough room to display the `Flyout`, it will be automatically moved to a `Placement` of `Top`. Even if I define the margin of the `FlyoutPresenter` Style to have -4 bottom margin, it doesn't appear to be applied.

Is there a way to move the `Flyout`? I'd prefer not to use a `MenuFlyout` if possible, since nothing is meant to be selectable. Flyouts don't have a `Canvas` attached property, and updating the `Canvas.Top` position of the top-most child of the `Flyout` didn't work (and I didn't really expect it to).

**Edit:** The desired behavior is for the `Flyout` to appear in the `Top` `Placement`, as is happening, but without the space in between the `Flyout` and the `Target`.

Comment: Isn't this a good thing? You would rather see the fly out get cut off?

Comment: Sorry - I was unclear about the desired outcome. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Placing a Flyout section of [Quickstart: Adding a Flyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx):

> The flyout is shown using the preferred placement if there's space for it on the screen. If there isn’t enough space, like when the element is near the edge of the screen, the flyout is placed using this fallback order.

When the `placement` is set to `bottom`, if there is no enough space it will place on the top which is by designed.

> but without the space in between the Flyout and the Target

If the bottom has no enough space, the `Flyout` place on the top, at this time, the `margin` of `FlyoutPresenter` should be changed to `0,4,0,0` instead of `0,-4,0,0` to access the same effects as it is on the bottom. But you will not know whether the `Flyout` is place top or bottom, so as a workaround you can set `margin` to `0,-5,0,-5`for the `Border` element inside the control template of `FlyoutPresenterStyle` which can meet your requirements. For example:

```
<Button
        Canvas.Top="600"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Content="Open flyout">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout x:Name="flyout" Placement="Bottom">
                <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                    <Border
                                        Margin="0,-5,0,-5"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                        <ScrollViewer
                                            x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                            HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                            VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                            ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                                            <ContentPresenter
                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" />
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <TextBlock Text="This is some text in a flyout." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Another option is to not override the control template and to subscribe to the `Opened` event, compare positioning of the `Flyout` with the target, and if the `Flyout` is above the target, programmatically adjust the margin of the `FlyoutPresenterStyle`.